# Magento 2.4 and Abobe stock

Tags: magento2.4, adobe-stock

I have disable adobe stock integration, I don't want to use it. But when I try to add a picture on a cms page I get the error "Failed to retrieve Adobe Stock search files results: Client error..."

How can I disable this?

Can you help me?

Thank you and Best Regards